# Error while trying huge gremlin Queries in Data Stax Graph

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

All of this was run in datastax studio.

I have a gremlin query which needs addition of about 10 vertices and many edges.
I have written a gremlin query for this and it runs successfully.

Then i copied the same query twice but by changing some values. again this ran successfully

Then i tried the same query with different values in a different cell in datastax studio and got the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException
```

Comment: Is there more to that exception? That doesn't provide very much of a clue as to what is happening. You may also need to provide the gremlin you were running or server logs if that exception fails to be useful

Comment: +1 to Stephen's request for server logs. We (studio team) are working on improving the exception reporting for situations like this but for now you will need to check the DSE log to see what went wrong.